# OpenScad - extrude and bend projection

Tags: openscad

I have a **projection** that I'd like to extrude and bend, following a series of steps like: extrude 10mm, bend 30 deg, extrude 20mm, etc. Each extrusion must be perpendicular to the plane resulting the previous bend.

Is there a way to do it with OpenSCAD?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSCAD provides linear and rotational [extrusion](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/2D_to_3D_Extrusion). You can use rotate extrude to create a bend. You will need to do a series of linear and rotational extrusions and combine them.